# \slash vs \addslash in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In the bibliography, should one use `\slash` or `\addslash`
when working with `biblatex` in order to get a breakable slash.
The documentation says to use it when specifying styles, but
there is no mention of usage in the actual bibliography.
E.g.

```
 @online{abc,
         auhor = {The Author},
         title = {Read\addslash{}Write},
         ...}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\slash` is defined by the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\slash{/\penalty\exhyphenpenalty}
```

The penalty allows a line break right after the slash (unless the value of `\exhyphenpenalty` forbids it). Hyphenation of the word after the slash is not permitted, because the word is not followed by a glue.

`\addslash` is defined by `biblatex`:

```
\newrobustcmd*{\addslash}{%
  \unspace/\penalty\hyphenpenalty\hskip\z@skip}
```

`\unspace` makes some cleanup and removes a previous space (not needed here). Then the line break is allowed the same way as by `\slash`, except
`\hyphenpenalty` is used instead of `\exhyphenpenalty`, the default of LaTeX's kernel is a value of 50 in both cases.
And the zero glue added a the end is different, which allows the following word to be hyphenated.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\verb|\slash|:\\
The references\slash bibliography

\bigskip
\verb|\addslash|:\\
The references\addslash bibliography

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]